# jquery - toggle animation

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

I've got a sidebar that when you click a button the sidebar slides left `250px`, when you click the same button I want it to slide back `250px` - I am currently using jquery `.toggle` but as I'm fairly new to jquery I need to ask what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/zfc3V/13/

```
(function($){
  $('a.mobile-menu-icon').toggle(
    function(){
      $('#sidebar').animate({left: '250px'}, 700);
    },
    function(){
      $('#sidebar').animate({left: '0px'}, 700);
    });
});
```

I'm using 1.9.1 (before .toggle was removed) and UI is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) only shows or hides an element

Comment: [.toogle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is deprecated in jquery 1.8 and removed in 1.9

Comment: Replace the entire first line through `$(document).ready(function(){` for instance. Then you'll see toggle actually toggles your anchor. So you may want to change this first to see the effect of any of your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but the event is "click", not toggle. Maybe with this:

```
$('a.mobile-menu-icon').click( function(event){
 var trigger = $(this);
 if( trigger.hasClass("expanded")){
   trigger.removeClass("expanded");
   $('#sidebar').animate({left: '250px'}, 700);
 } else {
   trigger.addClass("expanded");
    $('#sidebar').animate({left: '0px'}, 700);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Shorthand for document.ready is `$(function(){ })`; not `function()`
2. If you want something to happen on click you have to add a `click event handler`.
3. You can use `CSS transitions` for the animation instead of `jQuery`.

   $(function($){
       $('a.mobile-menu-icon').on('click',function(){
           $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
       });
   });

http://jsfiddle.net/zfc3V/19/

Comment: For some reason SO markdown doesn't want to format the lines above as code.

Answer (score 0):

The `.toggle()` event was deprecated, and does not work in that function anymore. By adding a `data-open` property to your `<a>` it is very easy to create such a function. Here is the code that would do so. The only change that is required is making your `<a>` like so: `<a href="#" class="mobile-menu-icon" data-open="true">Click to toggle</a>`

```
$('a.mobile-menu-icon').click(function() {
    var x = $(this).data('open');
    $('#sidebar').animate({left: (x) ? '250px' : '0px'}, 700);
    x ? $(this).data('open', false) : $(this).data('open', true);
});
```

Here's a fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zfc3V/18/

Comment: One problem with this code is that if you click the toggle anchor multiple times, the animation will repeat and be added to queue. Use `stop()` to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @Cristy When adding `.stop()` to the example in the fiddle, it stops the animation from running, adding `queue: false` seems to solve the problem though.

Comment: Yes I meant using the `stop()` function, the parameters usually used for this are `.stop(0,1)` I think.

Comment: @Cristy Ah, okay. I'm used to using `queue`, so I was unaware that `.stop()` needed parameters. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead
**JS:**

```
$('a.mobile-menu-icon').on("click", function() {
  $('#sidebar').toggleClass('show');
});
```

**Css:**

```
#sidebar {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .7s ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
}

#sidebar.show {
  left: 250px;
}
```